# How to create image slide show with fixed text?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I want to create a slide show of images in which the image in background slides one by one but the text should float over it.

The final thing I want to achieve is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSwtg.png).

I have followed the post in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh920769%28v=vs.85%29.ASPX) article, I downloaded the `slideShow.js` file and applied on the images and it's working perfectly. Now how do I float the text over the image?

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <title>Slide Show</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    .size
    {
        height:300px;
        width:500px;
    }
    .lab
    {}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>

        <label class="lab">This is Label</label>
      <div id="slideShowImages">
        <img src="1.jpg" alt="Slide 1" class="size" />
        <img src="2.jpg" alt="Slide 2" class="size"/>
        <img src="3.jpg" alt="Slide 3" class="size"/>    
        <img src="4.jpg" alt="Slide 4" class="size"/>
      </div>  
    </div>
  <script src="slideShow.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The label would be the text displayed over image.
Please help.

Comment: post fiddle ..it help us to find the problem easly

Comment: visit this link:[http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/)create your code by using this editer .you have to load the external javascript (slideshow.js)in External resources

Comment: kindly link slideshow doc site

Answer (score 1):

Install WoW Slider and import all the images to be slided and also you can give text for each and every image so that while the image slides the corresponding text will also come along with it

http://wowslider.com/ - You can choose your favourite sliding template

Comment: Its a lightweight Javascript file so that it will load your page quickly